# How to use a variable in a function that is created via the exec()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run the following code

```
def foo():
    exec('foo_value = 1')
    
def foo2():
    foo()
    print(globals()['foo_value'])

foo2()
```

But i get the error `KeyError: 'foo_value'`

Is there a way to be able to use the `foo_value` inside the `foo2` function, while the `foo_value` is created inside another function via the `exec()` ?

Comment: this is highly suspect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `foo_value` a global variable by doing this: `exec('global foo_value;foo_value = 1')`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a global from inside a function, you need the global keyword. ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423596/2339067))

```
def foo():
    global foo_val
    foo_val = 1
```

That should make it work. (Or `exec('global foo_val;foo_val=1')` inside an exec call)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When you run the exec function, the code runs in a local scope. In order to make the code accessible to globals simply you can set your global scope in exec code like:

```
def foo():
    exec('foo_value = 1', globals())
    
def foo2():
    foo()
    print(globals()['foo_value'])

foo2() #output: 1
```

Comment: Was not aware of the extra parameters of `exec`, good to know! I think I like that more.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a function called `eval()`, it is very similar to `exec()`, but you could get the returned value of `eval()`

```
def foo():
    global foo_val
    fool_val = eval("1")
```

Although both of them could convert string to code, I strongly don't recommend you using them, because they are unsafe.